# How to add Angular2 in Cordova VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, angular

I need to know how to work with Angular2 in my Cordova Application, I already know how to install Angular2 alone and all things works fine.

I also followed the steps in [MSDN Microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7bf986c5-027b-434c-b0d8-c910c983030d/how-install-angular-2-with-dependencies-in-vs-2015-cordova-typescript-project?forum=ToolsForApacheCordova) but i think there is something missing.

Note: i used most of the Github links which show how Angular/Cordova works but each project has some unresolved errors and i couldn't find a good/working example

Comment: Have you tried these templates? https://www.visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b21470f5-d29f-44a1-8f4b-8a3f96ac5860

Comment: That is not what I am looking for this is ionic 2

Comment: Could you add some details about `each project has some unresolved errors`?